# Differentiate the following w.r.t. $\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus

**Differentiate** : $$ \tan^{-1}  \left(\frac {\sqrt {1+x^2}-1}x\right) \quad w.r.t.\quad \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right) $$

Comment: Please clarfy whether 'tan inverse' means $\mathrm{arctan}$ or $1/\tan$, and whether 'xsq' means $x^2$ or $\sqrt{x}$ or something else. At present your question is hard to understand.

Comment: And what does 'sq root 1 + Xsq - 1 / x' mean? $(\sqrt{1} + Xsq - 1)/x$? $(\sqrt{1 + Xsq }- 1)/x$? $\sqrt{1 + Xsq } - 1/x$? Please add brackets when appropriate and learn how to format mathematical expressions from [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is 'tan inverse'? $\mathrm{arctan}$ or $\cot$?

Comment: $$ \tan^{-1} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question have been solved by assuming tan inverse is “arc tan“.
    put x=tanθ and simplify 
 →arc tan(√1+tan²θ -1/tanθ)

→arc tan(√sec²θ -1/tanθ)

→arc tan(2sin²(θ/2)/sinθ)    (on simplifying)

→arc tan(2sin²(θ/2)/2sinθcosθ)

→arc tan(tan(θ/2))        =θ/2

→but θ=arc tan(x)

hence develops to →(1/2)arc tan(x) & term it as “u“.

also, arc tan(2x/1-x²)= 2arc tan(x)→“v“

finally, du/dx =1/4   (on simplifying with the above “u“ &“v“ )

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\tan^{-1}  \left(\dfrac {\sqrt {1+x^2}-1}x\right)$
and let $u= \tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$.

We want to find $dy/du$. Note that:
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2(1+x^2)}
$$
similarly for $u$, we obtain:
$$
\dfrac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{2}{1+x^2} \iff \dfrac{dx}{du} = \dfrac{1+x^2}{2}
$$
Hence, by Chain Rule, we obtain:
$$
\dfrac{dy}{du} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} \cdot \dfrac{dx}{du} = \dfrac{1}{2(1+x^2)} \cdot \dfrac{1+x^2}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: how did u do dy/dx. I cannot understand can u plzz explain me .. plzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 2):

Putting $x=\tan\theta,$

$$\quad \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right) $$
$$=\quad \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}\right) $$
$$=\quad \tan^{-1}(\tan2\theta)=n\pi+2\theta=n\pi+2\tan^{-1}x $$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\frac {\sqrt {1+x^2}-1}x=\frac {\sqrt {1+\tan^2\theta}-1}{\tan\theta}=\frac {\sqrt {1+\tan^2\theta}-1}{\tan\theta}=\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{1-\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}2}{1+\tan^2\frac{\theta}2}}{\frac{2\tan\frac{\theta}2}{1+\tan^2\frac{\theta}2}}=\tan\frac{\theta}2$$

$$\implies\tan^{-1}  \left(\frac {\sqrt {1+x^2}-1}x\right) \quad=\tan^{-1} \left(\tan\frac{\theta}2 \right)=m\pi+\frac{\theta}2=m\pi+\frac12\tan^{-1} x $$  where $m$ is any integer

So, $$\frac{d \tan^{-1}  \left(\frac {\sqrt {1+x^2}-1}x\right) \quad}{d  \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)}=\frac{d(m\pi+\frac12\tan^{-1} x )}{d (n\pi+2\tan^{-1}x )}=\frac{\frac{d(m\pi+\frac12\tan^{-1} x )}{d(\tan^{-1} x)}}{\frac{d (n\pi+2\tan^{-1}x)}{d(\tan^{-1} x})}$$