# Differenciating a function with respect to another function confusion

Tags: functions, trigonometry, derivatives, substitution, chain-rule

I am having problem solving the following question-

Differenciate $\tan^{(-1)}{(\sqrt{1-x^2}/x)}$ with respect to $\cos^{(-1)}{(2x\sqrt {1-x^2})}$, where $x$ is not $0$.

My attempt -

I took the tan function as $a$ and cos one as $b$.

Now we need ${(da/dx)/(db/dx)} $

So here if I substitute $x=\cos\theta$

or $x=\sin\theta$,

da/dx is $-1/(\sqrt{1-x^2})$.

Now for the second function if I substitute  $x=\cos\theta$ or $x=\sin\theta$ I dont get the same answer. Why is it so?

My book has taken $x$ to be between $-1/\sqrt{2}$ and $1/\sqrt{2}$ for the second function and hence arrived at the answer 0.5.My book says $x=\sin\theta $

is correct and $x=\cos\theta $

is wrong. How is this implied from the question?

P.S.-[1st page](http://postimg.org/image/s6zvrrb1z/full), [2nd page](http://postimg.org/image/kcza6d393)

Please help

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437341/differentiate-the-following-w-r-t-tan-1-left-frac2x1-x2-right

Comment: @labbhattacharjee this question is more ambiguous having gone through that question I still cant solve this one. Please help me understand what substitutions to make here as x=$sin\theta$ and x=$cos\theta$ yield a different result i.e 0.5 and -0.5 respectively.

Comment: The answer is 0.5

Comment: Please see http://postimg.org/image/s6zvrrb1z/full/ and http://postimg.org/image/kcza6d393/ . How have they determined the range of x ?

Answer (score 2):

By the substitution indicated in the numerator

$$  \dfrac{d(\tan^{-1}{\dfrac {\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x})}}{d[ \cos^{-1}2 x{\sqrt{1-x^2}]} }= \dfrac{d\varphi}{d(\cos^{-1} (sin 2 \varphi)}= \dfrac{d \varphi}{d(\pi/2 - 2 \varphi)}= \mp \dfrac12.$$

EDIT 1:

Due to presence of square-root *either sign* is correct in full domain. Sign change outside $  x= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  $

[image: RatesComparision]

Comment: The answer  is 0.5 @Narasimham. Even i got the answer you are getting but its wrong.

Comment: My book says x=sin$\theta $ is correct and not x=cos $\theta $ using the domain of x.

Comment: Please see http://postimg.org/image/s6zvrrb1z/full/   and http://postimg.org/image/kcza6d393/ @Narasimham How have they determined the range of x?

Comment: Both are right. This happens $always$ with  a sqrt . Please see my plot above for a total domain consideration.

Comment: Yes i understand now...that means my book is wrong ?

Comment: Not wrong, but incomplete. It is possible to draw a polar diagram to identify in which parts of the 4 quadrants function of $\varphi $  is >0 and in which parts <0.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider the above figure. The blue curve shows the function
$$y:=f(x):=\arctan{\sqrt{1-x^2}\over x}\ ,$$
and the orange curve shows the function
$$z:=g(x):=\arccos\bigl(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\bigr)\ ,$$
both in the interval $-1< x<1$. Due to the usual conventions concerning $\sqrt{\mathstrut\cdot}$ and the inverse trigonometric functions there are $4$ different regimes to be seen in the intervals $$-1<x<-{1\over\sqrt{2}},\qquad -{1\over\sqrt{2}}<x<0,\qquad 0<x<{1\over\sqrt{2}},\qquad {1\over\sqrt{2}}<x<1\ .$$
It follows that there are four different functions $\psi_k:\ z\mapsto y$ at stake here.

For the case $0<x<{1\over\sqrt{2}}$ introduce the auxiliary variable $\theta$ by means of
$$x:=\sin\theta\quad\left(0<\theta<{\pi\over4}\right)\ .$$
Then $\sqrt{1-x^2}/x=\cot\theta$, and
$$\hat y(\theta)=\arctan(\cot\theta)={\pi\over2}-\theta\ .$$
Furthermore $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin(2\theta)$. As $0<2\theta<{\pi\over2}$ we therefore obtain
$$\hat z(\theta)=\arccos\bigl(\sin(2\theta)\bigr)={\pi\over2}-2\theta\ .$$
It follows that under this regime we have  $y={\pi\over4}+{z\over2}$, so that
$${dy\over dz}\equiv{1\over2}\ .$$
For the case ${1\over\sqrt{2}}<x<1$ introduce the auxiliary variable $\theta$ by means of
$$x:=\sin\theta\quad\left({\pi\over4}<\theta<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$
Then we still have $\sqrt{1-x^2}/x=\cot\theta$, and
$$\hat y(\theta)=\arctan(\cot\theta)={\pi\over2}-\theta\ .$$
Furthermore $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin(2\theta)$, but now ${\pi\over2}<2\theta<\pi$. This leads to
$$\hat z(\theta)=\arccos\bigl(\sin(2\theta)\bigr)=2\theta-{\pi\over2}\ .$$
It follows that under this regime we have  $y={\pi\over4}-{z\over2}$, so that
$${dy\over dz}\equiv-{1\over2}\ .$$
I leave the two other regimes to you.

Comment: That means my book is wrong then to consider x only in the 2nd and 3rd regime right  ?

Comment: Please see postimg.org/image/s6zvrrb1z/full and postimg.org/image/kcza6d393